# SPD 2013 - Copy people picker field to text field in same list

Tags: workflow

My goal is to copy a people picker field as a text field within the same list, and my understanding is that this may be possible by copying the item to an intermediary list and then back to the original list?

Could someone please share in detail a workflow to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: you mentioned that you had found a way to copy over office fields from the people picker via a workflow. Can you tell me how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need to copy from a person & group column to a single text column

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Now what would one do if you wanted to copy to text the result of people picker fields that fall outside of the four listed options for the return field in the Update List Item action? - i.e. Display Name, Email Address, Login Name, or User ID Number. Meaning, I would like to copy over the Title, Office, and Phone Number fields I've pulled, but cannot find a way outside this action to do it. Again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Found a simply way to do it via a workflow. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: could you please mark my answer as "accepted"? by clicking on ✅