# How to show SharePoint People picker for Contact in Workflow email?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, people-picker, sharepoint-email

Sharepoint allows to extract user details like contact, location etc via a people picker field.

But when I have to display this contact (people picker) in workflow email it shows user name instead of Actual contact. It is pulling contact fine when displayed in list, edit form or display form.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the Name or Name (linked to itme) in *In this column:* when creating the column;

[image]

In the workflow you need to change the return variable type from *String* to *Lookup Value (As Text)*

[image]

Comment: Mine isnt a lookup field. Its a Person field named "User Contact" . When I created the column I had selected "Show Information as" = Mobile Phone. And thus, while displaying in WF it gives me options as Person field only ie As a String,Login name, display name, email address and user Id number. I have tried all options of display and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

It’s by default the workflow email text can only return Login name, display name, email address and user Id number.

As a workaround, you can use Rest Api to retrieve the user profile from people picker , here is a similar post for your reference:

[Is it possible to extract additional fields from people picker in a workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234646/is-it-possible-to-extract-additional-fields-from-people-picker-in-a-workflow)